# Set specific background color in iOS LaunchScreen.storyboard (Visual Studio for Mac)

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xamarin-studio

Ok, I can't believe I'm asking this but... how do you set a specific color as the background of a UIView. I mean:

- I select the UIView.
- I set #2374A5 as the background color (using the color picker).
- Visual Studio sets #1D5F93 as the background color (what??).

**EDIT:** Ok, just after I posted the question I remembered that I could actually edit the Storyboard in XCode Interface Builder and, there, it worked as expected. However, I'm still puzzled as to why VS changes the color I choose. Is it a bug, or is there any obtuse logic behind it that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Did you ever find out what was happening? The Launch Storybaord BG colour is weird. Whilst I can set it using XCode thatis most certianbly not the colour it renders. When I anayalyse screenshots from device of Launch screen compared to other screens the "same" colour is rendered differently

Comment: Hi @PatLong-MunkiiYebee, no, XCode/Interface Builder worked for me, so I didn’t investigate it any further :(